# Getting the TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Tags: python, lambda

Why do I seem to get this TypeError:

```
mx = list(lambda points: [str(Point(*point)) for point in points])
TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

All seems fine to me. `points` is an iterable.

```
class Point(object):    
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
            
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Pointxxxx(%d, %d)" % (self.x, self.y)

points = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10)]  
mx = list(lambda points: [str(Point(*point)) for point in points])
print(mx)
```

Comment: `list` function takes `iterable` object as parament not a function.

Comment: Check your `mx = ...` line of code

Comment: Is there a reason you even use a `lambda` here? Why not just `mx = [str(Point(*point)) for point in points]`?

Comment: That's not one of them... `lambda`s are used when something is actually ***expecting*** a function. For example: `sorted(l, key=lambda x: x*2)`. Here, the `key` argument is a function

Comment: @MathMan I didn't downvote for using lambda. I commented to try and understand your rational to try and help you. Commenting doesn't corelate with downvoting

Comment: You should also ask about ***your*** code. Asking about random code you don't even understand is not very productive to anyone

Comment: @Tomerikoo Okay my bad. I don't understand why would someone downvote the question. I am in the self-learning phase and I can't invent my own code when I have just been introduced to lambda functions.

Comment: So you should look for sources online and read about `lambda`s and how to use them. Look at examples until you get the hang of it. Then start with basic exercises and work your way up. Rushing to ask here for every little thing you don't understand makes for low quality questions that are hard to answer and hurts your learning process. Stack Overflow should really be your last resort in your self-learning process. I wish you all the good luck!

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thank you and I agree. I have already read about lambda functions and how to use them. But, how do I resolve very special cases like these that I just posted which are not found in any online book/resource?

Comment: As I said, practice and work with it a bit to get the hang of it. The key point you're missing in this case is that a `lambda` returns a function object in the end. Passing that to the `list` constructor doesn't make much sense. You need to actually call that `lambda` on the input list, like `(lambda points: ...)(points)` but that should raise a red flag. If you only define a *nameless* function to call it once with a single argument, why not just run the function's body? Which is what I said in my first comment

Comment: @Tomerikoo Aaah okayy.... Got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list` function takes iterable object as parament not a function.
Change your code `list(lambda points: [str(Point(*point)) for point in points])`

```
function = lambda points: [str(Point(*point)) for point in points]
mx = list(function(points))
```

---

Or use

```
mx = [str(Point(*point)) for point in points]
```

---

Or use `map` function for that purpose

```
mx = list(map(lambda points: [str(Point(*point)) for point in points], [points]))
```

Comment: That last suggestion is really an anti-pattern and I wouldn't recommend anyone to use it...

Comment: why as result is just a `list inside list` which we unpack using `*`

Comment: The point of `map` is to apply a function on all items of an iterable. If you wrap your list in a nother list just to make an iterable of one item, is an anti-pattern... Just call the function on that item instead of calling it with `map` on an iterable of one item...